# User can't log in to Drupal Site from another Domain which have 2 domains

Tags: drupal, dns

I have www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com which pointed to same vHost drupal site.

www.domain1.com is old domain and we want to redirect to new domain www.domain2.com. I'm using .htaccess to redirect from domain1.com to domain2.com and it's working perfectly.

Problem is users aren't able to log in to domain2.com but don't have any problem in domain1.com. I had checked the 'settings.php' file for the configuration. Both '$base_url' and '$cookie_domain' is under comment. I tried to give the setting for those 2 variables as below below but still no luck.

$base_url = 'http://www.domain2.com'
$cookie_domain = '.domain2.com'

It doesn't seem to be accept the cookies. I try to access the url without www in this format 'domain2.com' and it's prompt the log in access and when I try to skip the error it's show as below header with'

'**401 Authorization Required**'.

> Authorization Required
>
> This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the
>   document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g.,
>   bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the
>   credentials required.*

I had been stuck in this for quite sometime and really appreciate your suggestions and answers.

Comment: is this an entirely new site or just domain? have you moved the sql database? Do you have those users setup if it's a new installation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that you have cleared the menu cache, and that the drupal site knows it is at the new URL?

It may be that you are actually submitting the authentication request to domain1.com, which is being intercepted by the server and redirecting to domain2.com

Comment: Yes. I had disable the caches before moving to new domain. There are some files under the caches folder.Am I need to clear those as well? Or am I need to configure the server ip in Setting.php at below?

$conf = array(
     'cache_inc' => './sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache.inc',
        'memcache_servers' => array('xxx.xx.xx.xxx:11211' => 'default',
                              'xxx.xx.xx.xxx:11211' => 'default',
                              'xxx.xx.xx.xxx:11211' => 'default',
                              'xxx.xx.xx.xxx:11211' => 'default'),
    'memcache_key_prefix' => 'mh',
); Thanks.